# select from insert into not working with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, db2

I want to insert a record in `mytable` (in DB2 database) and get the `id` generated in that insert. I'm trying to do that with `python 2.7`. Here is what I did:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
import ibm_db_sa

db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://user:pswd@localhost:50001/mydatabase')
sql = "select REPORT_ID from FINAL TABLE(insert into MY_TABLE values(DEFAULT,CURRENT TIMESTAMP,EMPTY_BLOB(),10,'success'));"
result = db2.execute(sql)
for item in result:
    id = item[0]
print id
```

When I execute the code above it gives me this output:

```
10 //or a increasing number
```

Now when I check in the database nothing has been inserted ! I tried to run the same SQL request on the command line and it worked just fine. Any clue why I can't insert it with python using `sqlalchemy` ?

Comment: Did you forget to commit?

Comment: @Lennart I don't think that `commit` is the problem because when I run a simple `INSERT INTO` with the same code it insert the record correctly.

Comment: should the `;` be included in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try a commit? @Lennart is right. It might solve your problem.

Your code does not commit the changes you have made and thus are rolled back.
If your Database is InnoDB, it is transactional and thus needs a commit.

according to [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#using-transactions), you also have to connect to your engine. so in your instance it would look like:

```
db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://user:pswd@localhost:50001/mydatabase')
conn = db2.connect()
trans = conn.begin()
try:
    sql = "select REPORT_ID from FINAL TABLE(insert into MY_TABLE values(DEFAULT,CURRENT TIMESTAMP,EMPTY_BLOB(),10,'success'));"
    result = conn.execute(sql)
    for item in result:
        id = item[0]
    print id
    trans.commit()
except:
    trans.rollback()
    raise
```

I do hope this helps.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `trans.rollback()` necessary? I would think that if you never `commit()`, it should `rollback()`, and I would think if your `trans` encountered an exception, you'd want to `conn.end()` or `trans.end()` or whatever the case might be? I'm not sure about any of the above though; trying to check my assumptions. Otherwise, though, this solved my issue. Not sure why other `INSERT` statements succeed without requiring a `commit()`, but that's for a different post, I guess. Anyways, thanks!